# HashMap: safe for multithreaded access for multiple readers and one single writer?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

I'm reading the docs for [`java.util.HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), and it says:

> If multiple threads access this map concurrently, and at least one of
>   the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized
>   externally.

**What does "it" mean?** "it" could be interpreted to mean the thread that modifies the map, or it could mean the map itself.

Both the "safe for multiple threads reading" and "safe only on single thread when there is a writer" cases are no brainers (at least to me), which makes me believe that calling the "multiple readers and single writer" case speciffically in the documentation means the statement should be interpreted as "safe to have multiple threads reading and a single thread writing", rather than the no brainer "lock everything when you have a writer".

More so, the hashtable implementation in .Net is (unambiguously) documented as:

> Hashtable is thread safe for use by multiple reader threads and a single writing thread

(the .Net classes are not thread safe by default), so there must be something to the "multiple reader threads and one single writer thread" case.

Comment: Synchronizing a thread is meaningless. You synchronize objects to regulate access by threads. This is basic Java. I fail to see what .NET has to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal elements are in an indeterminate state when a thread "modifies the map structurally" so reads could be affected. Thus the requirement to use some method external to the map to synchronize both reads and writes.

Perhaps the writers of the .Net library were more careful to keep their internal structure in a determinate state during updates.

Answer (score 0):

The map itself. HashMap is not thread safe.

Look at [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), it is a thread-safe map.

You also can manage it by yourself. The code maybe looks like below

```
class SomeClass {

    private Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    public synchronized void put(Object key, Object value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public synchronized Object get(Object key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

More safer, return the copy of the value object to avoid unexpected behaviors.

```
public synchronized ValueType get(Object key) {
    return map.get(key).clone(); // assume that the ValueType implements Cloneable
    // of course, you can return a copy in many ways you like
}
```

This will only allow the `put` method to modify the map. And all the operations will be thread-safe.

Comment: Hi @scarcer. The "HashMap is not thread safe" statement is not quite true. A HashMap instance is:  
<br/>- guaranteed to be thread-safe when all the threads are doing read-operations  
<br/>- not safe when multiple threads are doing concurent write operations  
<br/>- [this question above]: when concurently, multiple threads are doing reads, and one thread is writing

Comment: @daniel "A HashMap instance is guaranteed to be thread-safe when all the threads are doing read-operations", this is incorrect. See Mark's answer.

Comment: @daniel, Steve Kuo, here is my opinion. If all threads are doing read-operations(which means not only read the map, but also read the element that you read from the map), since the structure of the map and elements of the map don't change, of course we can expect that every thread can get the same value. But if the structure or the elements themselves changed, it won't be thread-safe any more. The most safe way is: synchronize your read method, and return the copy of the value object. See my post please.